How the Open API controller/service is added?
I am using NSwag to generate the controller code for a c# Open API service
Then, in Program.cs, it is just a simple code from the sample project
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I can run and test the service, which is fine here.
But what I do not understand is that I do not specify the generated controller class name in the method call of builder.Services.AddControllers() or app.MapControllers().
How does the runtime know which controller it should use, what/where is the magic?
Is it something done by reflection by the underlying framework? I mean to loop all the classes and find those implementing the controller interface?
If this is the case, any reason why it is designed like that, a bit not easy to understand.
For grpc or hosted service, we at least need to specify the class (services.AddGrpcClient/services.AddHostedService) to handle it, but why not the open api controller?

You could always take a look at the source code for SwaggerBuilderExtensions and SwaggerUIBuilderExtensionsto figure this out.

Short answer: it uses reflection to discover all the controller classes and their action methods.

It looks like AddSwagger() and AddSwaggerUI() both register middleware into the request pipeline so it can intercept the requests without needing reflection.

However, MapControllers() does indeed use reflection.
